# Angular nested components data flow with NGRX-Data

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs6, angular-ngrx-data

I have a two components whith a shared service and the service is connected to an NGRX Data store. The `Button-Component` triggers a request via the service by calling the `getByKey()` method of NGRX-Data. The `Display-Component` has an Observable which is subscribed with the async pipe.

```js
// Observable subscribed with async pipe
identifiers$: Observable<Identifiers> = new Observable<Identifiers>();

// Method called by the `Button-Component`
callApi(key) {
    // When this emits I want to map the value to `identifiers$`
    this.service.getByKey(key);
}
```

So far I'm not able to trigger the call with the Subscrption in the `Display-Component`. It works if I manually subscribe in the Service and the `entities$` in the Store are updated too. I could use that but then I need some logic to store the `key` which I would like to avoid.

So how can I map from the Observable returned by the Store to the one of the `Display-Component` in one go?

Answer (score 1):

The store is share for all child modules and their components, if you use `.forRoot` in `AppModule` then it means all the application is connected to the same store and shares its data.

In your case I would check the selector of `identifiers$` to ensure what and how it receives because the described flow works in ngrx-data and doesn't require any additional changes.